# Reverse geocoding with botframework.location

Tags: geolocation, location, botframework

In the database is stored `place_id`. This `place_id` has been stored in database when the user saves location.

Is it possible to make reverse geo coding using [botframework.location](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Location) ? Something like [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-place-id). ?

Comment: Please give it a try, and if you run into difficulty, post your code here and the community will assist you.

Comment: I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use [Bing Maps REST Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701713.aspx) and the BotFramework, to "geocode and reverse-geocode location data".

Edit:
You could start by going over: [Geocoding a Location](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427601.aspx)

Here is how to Find a Location by Point: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701710.aspx

It's as easy as retrieving a Bing Maps Key (either from within the Bing Maps Portal: https://www.bingmapsportal.com/ or through the Azure Portal, by adding Bing Maps API via the Marketplace https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/bingmaps.mapapis ), and using the key in this url:
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/47.64054,-122.12934?o=xml&key=[YourBingMapsKey]

There's also this informative documentation about how to use the BotFramework's Location control: https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/bot-intelligence/location-control/

Comment: How to make that request ? Is there any example about finding a location by point (lat/long) ? It would be awesome if you can post some useful links.
Thanks.

Comment: I've edited the answer with some links and description of how to retrieve a Bing Maps Key and use it to find a location by point.